# How can I apply a style to a span of text that transcends other elements' boundaries?

Tags: html, dom, web

Let's suppose I have the following paragraphs:

```
<p>one two </p> <p> three </p><p> four five </p>
```

Now let's suppose I want to style the words two, three, and four green, in place, without having any other effect on the document's structure or other layout. I basically want a `<span>` that transcends block level elements like `<p>`s. How can I accomplish this most simply? I could

```
<p>o <span>t</span></p><p><span>t</span></p><p><span>f</span> f</p>
```

But that makes things really messy due to the fact that I employ a markdown parser and have my own custom preprocessing code. What could I do so that there's only one "style begin" mark, and only one "style end" mark per contiguous length of green text?

Comment: What do you mean by parsed?

Comment: something like `document.querySelectorAll('span p')` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0):

You can have your text wrapped in a single `<p> </p>` and have a `<span>` inside that wrapping around the text you want to style, so:

```
<p>one <span>two three four</span> five</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/asbd9rdj/

*edit*

To target specific words in your multiple `<p></p>` tags, use a `<span></span>` as an inline element so you can attach styles to it.

```
<p>one <span>two</span></p>
<p>three <span>four</span></p>
```

example here: http://jsfiddle.net/79be8L6L/

Comment: That just changes the questions of the parameter, doesn't it?

Comment: @user261849 If you want to remain using multiple `<p></p>` tags like the example in your question rather than using only a single `<p></p>` then i would recommend using inline elements (span) to target your specific styled words. `<span></span>` will only have a semantic value if you assign a class to it.

Comment: Right. I will assign classes. However, I know that HTML5 has inbuilt deterministic error tolerance, and I'm asking how I can expect such markup to be parsed into DOM fragments.

Answer (score 0):

"Interleaving" HTML tags [is invalid](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Validating_your_HTML#Different_browsers_interpret_invalid_HTML_differently). You should use 3 separate `<span>` tags, like in your second example.

Making your HTML generator handle this is unfortunately a necessary complexity in order to produce proper HTML.